# Initialization to same variable

Tags: c++

I just found this as a mistype in my unit testing code:

```
Binding binding(x, y, z);
Binding moved(std::move(moved));  // Should be `std::move(binding)`
```

Why is this valid code? What is happening here? Shouldn't this be an error?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string x(std::move(x));
    std::cout << '"' << x << '"' << std::endl;
}
```

[Compiled with gcc 4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b7097cc7f1b4257)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's valid <sup>*</sup>(depending on the definition of `Binding`) because the name declared is known immediately from the point of declaration.

E.g.

```
struct Node { Node* next; int value; };
```

is one example of the same general principle, and

```
Node head = {&head, 0};
```

is a more direct example of a variable declaration using (or abusing) that idea.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup>If the code invokes a usual move constructor that attempts to move from an uninitialized object, then that's Undefined Behavior, and invalid in that sense.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. The example is a good example in C and I can understand how that maps to assembly. I guess in this case the `std::string` is move constructor is called with a pointer to the uninitialized stack storage.

Comment: Oh. I didn't see the `std::string` example. But now I looked closer... That examples is known UB, since `std::string` has an ordinary move constructor.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is this valid code?

It isn't. It's syntactically valid, but has undefined behaviour (assuming the constructor uses its argument).

> What is happening here?

Assuming the move constructor behaves as one would expect, `moved` is initialised using its own uninitialised value. Using an uninitialised value gives undefined behaviour.

> Shouldn't this be an error?

Maybe, but it isn't. You can access a variable's name within its initialiser, which can be legitimate as long as you don't use the value. For example, this:

```
void * p = &p;
```

is well-defined, initialising a pointer to point to itself.

Since it's passed by reference to a user-declared constructor, the compiler can't tell whether or not the value might be used, and so can't issue a warning.

Comment: re "`moved` is initialised using its own uninitialised value", it is the most *likely* thing to happen, knowing nothing about the class, but it really depends on the class. besides, the question is not very likely to be about that aspect.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Indeed, I was making a bit of an assumption there. The example in the link from the question (using `std::string` rather than an unknown `Binding`) certainly does do that.